Jacobian of a point transformation in phase space
A common basic result of analytical mechanics is that point transformations $Q=Q(q)$ are canonical, i.e. they preserve the canonical structure of Hamilton equations.
Also, a known theorem says that a necessary and sufficient condition for $(p,q) \to (P,Q)$ to be a canonical transformation is that its Jacobian $M$  has to be of the form $M J M^t=M^t J M = a J$, with $J$ the standard symplectic matrix and $a$ a constant different from zero.
As an exercise, I want to verify the theorem for a point transformation, but I am having trouble proving that $M^t J M = a J$ for dimension of $M$ higher than 2.
Being that $Q=Q(q)$ and $P=(N^t(q))^{-1}p$, where $N$ is the Jacobian of $Q(q)$ I write the Jacobian $M$ of the overall $(p,q) \to ((N^t)^{-1}p, Q(q))$ transformation as
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial P}{\partial p} & \frac{\partial P}{\partial q}\\
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} & \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
(N^t(q))^{-1} & R\\
0 & N
\end{bmatrix}$$
and I get $$
M^tJM=
\begin{bmatrix} 
(N(q))^{-1} & 0\\
R^t & N^t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -I\\
I & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
(N^t(q))^{-1} & R\\
0 & N
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
(N(q))^{-1} & 0\\
R^t & N^t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -N\\
(N^t(q))^{-1} & R
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -I\\
I & -R^tN+N^tR
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $R=[\frac{\partial (N^t(q))^{-1}p}{\partial q_1}...\frac{\partial (N^t(q))^{-1}p}{\partial q_n}]$
so that $$N^tR(i,j)=\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial Q_1}{\partial q_i} & ... &\frac{\partial Q_n}{\partial q_i}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial (N^t(q))^{-1}p}{\partial q_j}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
R^tN(i,j)=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial (N^t(q))^{-1}p}{\partial qi}
\end{bmatrix}^t\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial Q_1}{\partial q_j} & ... &\frac{\partial Q_n}{\partial q_j}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This last matrix is $J$ (so $a$ is 1) if $R^tN$ is symmetric, but I am not sure how to check it.
Is the reasoning and the methodology correct?

Minor comment to the post (v2): The standard order is $(q,p)$; not $(p,q)$.

@Qmechanic ah thanks. I am following the convention of my reference book "Analytical mechanics" (Fasano, Marmi). They also indicate the standard symplectic matrix as I have indicated in the question. do you suggest to reorder them? any other hint or comment is welcome thanks.

Sketched calculation using the standard order $z=(q,p)$ and $Z=(Q,P)$:

Under a coordinate transformation of positions
$$Q^i~=~f^i(q),\qquad N^i{}_j~:=~\frac{\partial Q^i}{\partial q^j}, $$
the momenta transform as a covector
$$ P_i~=~p_k\frac{\partial q^k}{\partial Q^i}~=~p_kL^k{}_i,$$
$$ P~=~L^tp, \qquad L~:=~N^{-1}, \qquad L^i{}_j~=~\frac{\partial q^i}{\partial Q^j}. $$

Jacobian matrix in phase space:
$$M^I{}_K ~=~\frac{\partial Z^I}{\partial z^K}~=~\begin{pmatrix} N & {\bf 0} \cr R & L^t\end{pmatrix}.$$

Condition for a symplectomorphism:
$$ MJM^t~=~\begin{pmatrix} {\bf 0} & {\bf 1} \cr -{\bf 1} & RL\!-\!(RL)^t\end{pmatrix}~=~\begin{pmatrix} {\bf 0} & {\bf 1} \cr -{\bf 1} &{\bf 0}\end{pmatrix}~=:~J.$$

In the last equation was used that
$$\begin{align} (RL)_{im}
~=~& R_{ij}L^j{}_m
~=~\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial q^j}L^j{}_m
~=~p_n\frac{\partial L^n{}_i}{\partial q^j}L^j{}_m\cr
~=~&-p_nL^n{}_{\ell}\frac{\partial N^{\ell}{}_k}{\partial q^j}L^k{}_iL^j{}_m\cr
~=~&-p_nL^n{}_{\ell}\frac{\partial^2 Q^{\ell}}{\partial q^j\partial q^k}L^k{}_iL^j{}_m
~=~(i\leftrightarrow m).\end{align}$$
$\Box$


